# Python YAML dump using block style without quotes

Tags: python, yaml

How do you load and dump YAML using PyYAML, so that it uses the original styling as closely as possible?

I have Python to load and dump YAML data like:

```
import sys
import yaml

def _represent_dictorder(self, data):
    # Maintains ordering of specific dictionary keys in the YAML output.
    _data = []
    ordering = ['questions', 'tags', 'answers', 'weight', 'date', 'text']
    for key in ordering:
        if key in data:
            _data.append((str(key), data.pop(key)))
    if data:
        _data.extend(data.items())
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', _data)

yaml.add_representer(dict, _represent_dictorder)

text="""-   questions:
    -   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    tags:
        context: curabitur
    answers:
    -   weight: 2
        date: 2014-1-19
        text: |-
            1. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.
            2. Donec pellentesque elit non felis feugiat, in gravida ex hendrerit.
            3. Mauris quis velit sapien. Nullam blandit, diam et pharetra maximus, mi erat scelerisque turpis, eu vestibulum dui ligula non lectus.
                a. Aenean consectetur eleifend accumsan.
            4. In erat lacus, egestas ut tincidunt ac, congue quis elit. Suspendisse semper purus ac turpis maximus dignissim.
                a. Proin nec neque convallis, placerat odio non, suscipit erat. Nulla nec mattis nibh, accumsan feugiat felis.
            5. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.
                a. Morbi non arcu odio. Maecenas faucibus urna et leo euismod placerat.
                b. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque at pretium nunc.
                c. Ut ipsum nibh, suscipit a pretium eu, eleifend vitae purus.
"""
yaml.dump(yaml.load(text), stream=sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, indent=4)
```

but this outputs the YAML in a different style, like:

```
-   questions:
    - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    tags:
        context: curabitur
    answers:
    -   weight: 2
        date: 2014-1-19
        text: "1. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.\n\
            2. Donec pellentesque elit non felis feugiat, in gravida ex hendrerit.\n\
            3. Mauris quis velit sapien. Nullam blandit, diam et pharetra maximus,\
            \ mi erat scelerisque turpis, eu vestibulum dui ligula non lectus.\n \
            \   a. Aenean consectetur eleifend accumsan.\n4. In erat lacus, egestas\
            \ ut tincidunt ac, congue quis elit. Suspendisse semper purus ac turpis\
            \ maximus dignissim.\n    a. Proin nec neque convallis, placerat odio\
            \ non, suscipit erat. Nulla nec mattis nibh, accumsan feugiat felis.\n\
            5. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.\n \
            \   a. Morbi non arcu odio. Maecenas faucibus urna et leo euismod placerat.\n\
            \    b. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque at pretium nunc.\n    c. Ut ipsum\
            \ nibh, suscipit a pretium eu, eleifend vitae purus."
```

As you can see, it's changing the style of the text-block, so that newlines are escaped, making it a lot harder to read.

So I tried specifying the `default_style` attribute like:

```
yaml.dump(yaml.load(text), stream=sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, default_style='|', indent=4)
```

And that fixed the text-block style, but then it broke other styles by putting quotes around all other strings, adding newlines to single-line strings, and munging integers, like:

```
-   "questions":
    - |-
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    "tags":
        "context": |-
            curabitur
    "answers":
    -   "weight": !!int |-
            2
        "date": |-
            2014-1-19
        "text": |-
            1. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.
            2. Donec pellentesque elit non felis feugiat, in gravida ex hendrerit.
            3. Mauris quis velit sapien. Nullam blandit, diam et pharetra maximus, mi erat scelerisque turpis, eu vestibulum dui ligula non lectus.
                a. Aenean consectetur eleifend accumsan.
            4. In erat lacus, egestas ut tincidunt ac, congue quis elit. Suspendisse semper purus ac turpis maximus dignissim.
                a. Proin nec neque convallis, placerat odio non, suscipit erat. Nulla nec mattis nibh, accumsan feugiat felis.
            5. Mauris lorem magna, auctor et tristique id, fringilla ut metus.
                a. Morbi non arcu odio. Maecenas faucibus urna et leo euismod placerat.
                b. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque at pretium nunc.
                c. Ut ipsum nibh, suscipit a pretium eu, eleifend vitae purus.
```

How do I fix this so the output resembles the style of my original input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would you determine what string to represent as a block literal (or a folded block for that matter) and what to represent inline?

Under the assumption that you only want block literals used with strings that span over multiple lines, you can write your own string representer to switch between the styles based on the string content:

```
def selective_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:str", data,
                                   style="|" if "\n" in data else None)

yaml.add_representer(str, selective_representer)
```

Now if you dump your data with default flow style set to `False` (to prevent `dict`/`list` inlining):

```
yaml.dump(yaml.load(text), stream=sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, indent=4)
```

Your scalars will act as you expect them to.

Comment: This doesn't fix it completely, but it comes close. It still seems to resort to the wrong style for very complex cases of text containing nested lists.

Comment: On further testing, I found the thing causing the dumper to escape each line was caused by lines containing nothing but whitespace (e.g. "\n    \n") which didn't match the outer scope's indentation. When I replaced this with just a series of newlines, that fixed the issue.